# How to use OSM offline maps in uwp?

Tags: c#, dictionary, win-universal-app, openstreetmap

I have a Zip file contain all Open Street Maps tiles for specific region. 
Is there any way to create a map using OSM tiles in universal windows apps?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: additionally why wont you use the stock microsoft maps? these are actually better for uwp integration. microsoft might of course have a tutorial for those!

Comment: Hi, @cramopy Can I use it in offline mode?

Comment: @NaserYousefi there are apps as I can get from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Windows_Phone , maybe you wanna contact one of the developers or take a look at a open source version of one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`CustomMapTileDataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.custommaptiledatasource.aspx). For each requested tile the event handler [`BitmapRequested`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.custommaptiledatasource.bitmaprequested.aspx) is called. In this handler you can pass any bitmap to the map.

In your case, you need to download the bitmaps beforehand and store it on the device. In the `BitmapRequested` handler you just deliver these bitmaps.

Comment: are you able to get it to work while there is no internet connection?

Comment: @aah134 download the OSM images beforehand, store them on the device and you're free to load them via a CustomMapTileDataSource as well without internet later.

Comment: I used to work with HttpMapTileDataSource however after changing to  CustomMapTileDataSource it worked. but map tiles edges black on top and bottom!!!